# Number of SQL Server languages

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156493%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> **There are currently ten SQL Server languages**. The report server
>   language for a given report server instance will always be one of the
>   ten available languages. Support for all ten of the SQL Server
>   languages is provided in a single Reporting Services installation.
>   There are no language packs to install.

However, as per the page for [sys.syslanguages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190303%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) there are many more listed

How should these 2 pages be interpreted together? Once says there are 10 SQL Server languages, and Report Server supports those 10. The other says there are many more, so are these supported by Report Server or not?

Answer (score 1):

You get 11 languages (well, 10 if you count us and british english as the same) from `SELECT DISTINCT language_id FROM sys.messages`
and 33 from `SELECT DISTINCT lcid FROM sys.syslanguages`.

If not listed in sys.messages, messages for the default language are used.

As for SSRS:

> If you install Reporting Services in a default configuration, Setup
>   determines the report server language when it creates the report
>   server database. The language resource that Setup uses is the one that
>   mostly closely matches the language of the operating system: If an
>   exact match between the operating system language and a SQL Server
>   language is found, Setup will use the exact match. For example, if the
>   operating system language is U.S. English, Setup will use the SQL
>   Server language resource for U.S. English as the report server
>   language. If an exact match cannot be found, a close match will be
>   used instead. For example, suppose the operating system is U.K.
>   English. Because U.K English and U.S. English are in the same language
>   family, Setup chooses the SQL Server language resource that most
>   closely matches U.K English (in this case U.S. English). If there is
>   no close match available, the report server language will be U.S.
>   English.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156493%28v=sql.105%29.aspx